# Random Number Python

Tags: python

So im trying to make a russian roulette game in python, and I need to like make it so that every time its that persons turn, and they spin the revolver, it selects a number from like 0 through 6
But is there a way I can like redefine the like random variable?
Like what I mean is that if I make variable thing = random.randrange(0,6) 
How would i like make thing equal to another random number from 0 through 6?
I think I explained it sort of but how would I do this? Im pretty good at programming but for some reason I just cant remember or know how to do it...
Also one quick question
If I did the like thing = random.randrange(0,6) thing would it give me a random number that is either, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 or would it be like 1,2,3,4,5
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

what about `random.randrange(1, 7)`?

As you can read [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_randrange.htm) the stop parameter won't be included while the start one will be.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [random module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html):

```
import random
var = random.randint(0,6)
```

using `randint` you will get the numbers you give it (i.e. 0,6 will give all 7 numbers, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6).

Comment: I know I do have that imported. So will that give me a number from 1,2,3,4,5,6?

Comment: @AviSchiffmann it will give 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. Edited to explain. If you want 1,2,3,4,5,6, use random.randint(1,6)